# How to set ListView Height to 5 elements in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have ListView and I would like that it occupies height for exactly 5 elements. If list has 2 items, there would be space left at the button. If list view has 8 items, user would need to scroll to view remaining 3 items. Is it possible in Xamarin Forms?

I tried to set HeightRequest, but I don't know height of items.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to subclass ListView and set the Element renderheight to calculate the total listview height. Am adding some similar code here which might help you.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
            BackgroundColor = Color.Silver;
            userListView = new ClistView();
            userListView.BackgroundColor = Color.Olive;
            userListView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
            userListView.ItemsSource = (BindingContext as MainViewModel).Items;
            userListView.SizeChanged += VisualElement_OnSizeChanged;
            userListView.RowHeight = 80;
            Content = userListView;
        }

        private void VisualElement_OnSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (userListView.HeightRequest < 0)
                userListView.HeightRequest = userListView.ElementHeight * 5;
        }
```

CListView - CustomListView

```
public class ClistView : ListView
    {
        public double ElementHeight { get; set; }

        protected override void SetupContent(Cell content, int index)
        {
            if (ElementHeight <= 0 && RowHeight <= 0)
                ElementHeight = content.RenderHeight;
            else
                ElementHeight = RowHeight;
            base.SetupContent(content, index);
        }
    }
```

[image: Final Image]